# Calculating the respective z-score of several columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a SQL query to determine the z-score (x - μ / σ) of several columns.

In particular, I have a table like the following:

```
my_table
id    col_a  col_b  col_c
1     3      6      5
2     5      3      3
3     2      2      9
4     9      8      2
```

...and I want to select the z-score of every number of every row, according to the average and standard deviation of its column.

So the result would look like this:

```
id    col_d     col_e     col_f
1    -0.4343    1.0203    ...
2     0.1434   -0.8729
3    -0.8234   -1.2323
4     1.889     1.5343
```

Currently my code computes the score for two columns and looks like this:

```
select id,
   (my_table.col_a - avg(mya.col_a)) / stddev(mya.col_a) as col_d,
   (my_table.col_b - avg(myb.col_b)) / stddev(myb.col_b) as col_e, 
from my_table,
select col_a from my_table)mya,
select col_b from my_table)myb
group by id;
```

However, this is extremely slow. I've been waiting minutes for a three column query.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I'm using postgres but any general language will help me. Thanks!

Comment: Some questions: 1) Why are you groping by ID? If it is a Primary Key then you won't be grouping anything 2) What is that `select col_a` doing there? 3) This is actually a comment. If you are not grouping anything then `avg(value)` will be equal to `value`

Comment: 1) I have no need to group by ID, however Postgres was saying "column 'my_table.id' must appear in the GROUP BY clause", so was doing so at the moment to avoid an error 2) Those selects do not need to be in the query, it's true.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use window functions like this:

```
select
    t.id,
    (t.col_a - avg(t.col_a) over()) / stdev(t.col_a) over() as col_d,
    (t.col_b - avg(t.col_b) over()) / stdev(t.col_b) over() as col_e
from my_table as t
```

or cross join with precalculated `avg` and `stdev`:

```
select
    t.id,
    (t.col_a - tt.col_a_avg) / tt.col_a_stdev as col_d,
    (t.col_b - tt.col_b_avg) / tt.col_b_stdev as col_e
from my_table as t
    cross join (
        select 
            avg(tt.col_a) as col_a_avg,
            avg(tt.col_b) as col_b_avg,
            stdev(tt.col_a) as col_a_stdev,
            stdev(tt.col_b) as col_b_stdev
        from my_table as tt
   ) as tt
```

Comment: Window functions. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: great solution. How about if you have null values in table ? it is zero / zero problem

Comment: @OğuzCanSertel a simple `CASE` statement in either select statement would suffice.

Comment: The standard deviation function is stddev in PostgreSQL 11.

Answer (score 0):

Using a WITH clause:

```
WITH stats AS ( SELECT avg ( col_a ) a_avg, stddev ( col_a ) a_stddev,
                       avg ( col_b ) b_avg, stddev ( col_b ) b_stddev
                    FROM my_table 
              )
SELECT id, ( col_a - a_avg) / a_stddev col_d, 
           ( col_b - b_avg) / b_stddev col_e
    FROM my_table, stats
```

But I like Roman's window solution better.

For  Oğuz: to deal with NULL values in my_table:

```
WITH stats AS ( 
              SELECT avg ( col_a ) a_avg, stddev ( col_a ) as a_stddev,
                     avg ( col_b ) b_avg, stddev ( col_b ) as b_stddev
                  FROM my_table 
              )
SELECT id, 
       COALESCE ( ( col_a - a_avg) / a_stddev, NULL ) col_d, 
       COALESCE ( ( col_b - b_avg) / b_stddev, NULL ) col_e
FROM my_table, stats
```

Answer (score -2):

I would start by selecting the avg() and stddev() attributes into a table variable and then use that table for the calculations

so you would get a table variable with the following columns 
AVG_col_a, stddev_col_a, AVG_col b, stddev_col_b ......

something like this

```
DECLARE @Table as table (AVG_col_a, stddev_col_a, AVG_col b, stddev_col_b ......)
INSERT into @Table
SELECT AVG(col_A), stddev(col_a), .......
FROM myTable

SELECT (m.col_a-AVG_col_a)/stddev_col_a as col_d,
       (m.col_b-AVG_col_b)/stddev_col_b as col_e
 FROM myTable m, @Table
```

Comment: Then he can use temp table, he says that any general language will help @mu is to short