# Creating Snowflake SDF that can take optional SQL as argument

Tags: sql, arguments, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions, optional-parameters

I've a simple function that calculates z-scores:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION z_score(x FLOAT)
  RETURNS FLOAT
  COMMENT = 'Simple z-score calculation.'
  AS 'NVL2(x, (x - AVG(x) OVER()) / STDDEV(x) OVER(), NULL)'
;
```

How can I extend the above definition to enable end user passing *optional* `PARTITION BY` / `ORDER BY` to the `OVER()` call so the score can be calculate within a group.

### Details

In a non-functional form the one can execute

```sql
SELECT 
  NVL2(x, (x - AVG(x) OVER(PARTITION BY group_col)) / STDDEV(x) OVER(
             PARTITION BY group_col), NULL) 
  FROM ...
```

Is it possible to mimic this behaviour in the function? It would like to make it possible to call function in two ways:

1. `z_score(x)` → No grouping argument. Executes:

   ```
   NVL2(x, (x - AVG(x) OVER()) / STDDEV(x) OVER(), NULL)
   ```
2. `z_score(x, PARTITION BY group_col)` → With grouping argument, generating statement from example. Executes:

   ```
   NVL2(x, (x - AVG(x) OVER(PARTITION BY group_col)) / STDDEV(x) OVER(
         PARTITION BY group_col), NULL)
   ```

### Example

```sql
--- Function experiment
CREATE
OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_some_values (group_col VARCHAR, x_val FLOAT);
INSERT INTO
    tmp_some_values
VALUES
    ('A', 786783),
    ('A', 7653.22),
    ('A', 75553.11),
    ('B', 1.33),
    ('B', 1.1),
    ('B', 1.2);
SELECT
    x_val,
    NVL2(x_val, (x_val - AVG(x_val) OVER()) / STDDEV(x_val) OVER(), NULL) AS z_score,
    NVL2(x_val,(x_val - AVG(x_val) OVER(PARTITION BY group_col)) / STDDEV(x_val) OVER(PARTITION BY group_col), NULL)  AS z_score_group
FROM
    tmp_some_values;
```

##### Results

| X_VAL | Z_SCORE | Z_SCORE_GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 786783 | 2.032252526 | 1.151122095 |
| 7653.22 | -0.4349140533 | -0.654227693 |
| 75553.11 | -0.2199045084 | -0.4968944024 |
| 1.33 | -0.4591442749 | 1.040531963 |
| 1.1 | -0.4591450032 | -0.9538209665 |
| 1.2 | -0.4591446866 | -0.08671099695 |

## Workaround solution

I was able to come up with a workaround using `IFF`

```sql
-- Define Z-Score calculating function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION z_score(x FLOAT, group_col VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL)
    RETURNS FLOAT
    COMMENT = 'Z-score calculation'
    AS
    $$
    IFF(group_col IS NULL,
        NVL2(x, (x - AVG(x) OVER ()) / STDDEV(x) OVER (), NULL),
        NVL2(x, (x - AVG(x) OVER (PARTITION BY group_col)) / STDDEV(x) OVER (PARTITION BY group_col), NULL)
        )
    $$
;
```

Still I would prefer a more intelligent way of handling optional SQL-like arguments.

Comment: Assuming that group_col has more than one value then isn’t the partition by statement going to return more than one value and therefore break your (scalar) function?

Comment: @Konrad Have you read this: https://medium.com/snowflake/snowflake-supports-named-and-optional-arguments-389d2500726f#:~:text=Snowflake%20now%20supports%20passing%20arguments,UDTFs)%2C%20and%20Stored%20Procedures. ? Looks like Snowflake now supports named arguments with defaults in a python fashion. So if you set your default to a constant the partition by <constant> would be moot.

Comment: @Error_2646 Thanks, I've seen the example you have mentioned in the [SF documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf-stored-procedure-arguments) what I'm curious about is how to make the `OVER` statement optional and able SQL syntax as an argument.

Comment: Hi - you still don’t seem to have addressed the issue that an OVER clause is going to generate multiple values and therefore makes your function unusable - and your question seems to be pointless

Comment: @NickW The z-score, should be generated for every *x*. The `OVER()` function is expected to generated multiple values, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279641/1655567) for a more detailed discussion on using `OVER()` statement in z-score calculation.